# NGX-Bootstrap - Angular - close tooltip manually

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I currently try to manually close a tooltip bye his inner button. I use the tooltipDirective to trigger either `tooltip.show()` or `tooltip.hide()` method. But it does not work. It is everytime saying `...elm.show() is not a function`. The used markup looks as follows:

```
<ng-template #tooltip>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="elm.hide()">Cancel</button>
</ng-template>

<button type="button" triggers="" placement="bottom" (click)="elm.show()"
         class="btn btn-success" [tooltip]="tooltip">
 Publish
</button>
```

Does anyone know how to close the tooltip from the component? The elm in the component looks as follows:

```
@ViewChild('tooltip') elm: TooltipDirective;
```

I provided a configured Stackblitz, to test around if it helps:[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-235xeh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger it manually you should refer to tooltip directive that resides on `button[tooltip]` in your template:

**html**

```
<button ... #tooltipTrigger="bs-tooltip" (click)="tooltipTrigger.show()"
```

*You may ask: where I find `bs-tooltip` string?*  (In source code https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/d9a89b427fa5c79d94cd609cdf574eaf7a143bf5/src/tooltip/tooltip.directive.ts#L25)

Also in order to close tooltip you have to override default behaviour with `pointer-events: none`

**global-styles.css**

```
.tooltip.tooltip.tooltip {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

or

```
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojy8gh?file=src%2Fstyles.css)**